# Enumeration Questionnaire type logic using javascript

Tags: javascript

Good day.
i'm trying to create enumeration type questionnaire, but i don't know the logic behind it. I want to know how to prevent this from counting as a correct. check the picture. [image]

also, it is correct if it is matched in the array list even it is not in order or in sequence.

Here's what i have tried and it is really messy. sorry

```js
var correctList = ['afghanistan','albania','algeria','argentina','armenia','angola']
var score = 0;
var yourAnswerAre = [];
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
document.querySelectorAll('.enumeration').forEach(input => {
var countNum = 1;
  correctList.forEach(list => {
     if(input.value == list){
     score++;
     yourAnswerAre.push({
            'Numb': countNum,
        'Answer': input.value,
        'IsCorrect': 'yes'
     })
   }else{
     score--;
     yourAnswerAre.push({
            'Numb': countNum,
        'Answer': input.value,
        'IsCorrect': 'no'
     })
   }
   countNum++
  })
})

document.querySelector('span').innerText = score;
console.log(yourAnswerAre)
})
```

```html
<label>score: <span>0</span></label>
<h3>
Give atleast 5 Country starts with letter A
</h3>
<input type="text" class="enumeration"/>
<input type="text" class="enumeration"/>
<input type="text" class="enumeration"/>
<input type="text" class="enumeration"/>
<input type="text" class="enumeration"/>
<button>
save
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were running through *all* of the possible answers against the inputs. I removed a `foreach` and used `includes` instead.

To guard against repeated inputs, I created the `used` array, which is set to true after an answer has been given.

```
 if (countries.includes(answer) && !used[countries.indexOf(answer)])
     {
     used[countries.indexOf(answer)]=true;
     ...
```

I added a martkung scheme with `insertAdjacentHTML`

```
   input.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", '<span style="color:red">&#10006</span>');
```

```js
var countries = ['afghanistan', 'albania', 'algeria', 'angola', 'argentina', 'armenia'];
var used = new Array(countries.length).fill(false);

var score = 0;
var yourAnswers = [];
var countNum = 1;

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
document.querySelectorAll('.enumeration').forEach(input => {
  var answer = input.value.toLowerCase();

  if (countries.includes(answer) && !used[countries.indexOf(answer)])
     {
     used[countries.indexOf(answer)]=true;
     score++;
     yourAnswers.push({
        'Number': countNum,
        'Answer': input.value,
        'Correct': 'yes'
     });
     input.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", '<span style="color:green">&#10003</span>');
   } else {
     yourAnswers.push({
        'Number': countNum,
        'Answer': input.value,
        'Correct': 'no'
     });
     input.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", '<span style="color:red">&#10006</span>');
   }
   countNum++;
  });

document.querySelector('label>span').innerText = score;

})
```

```html
<h3>Give 5 countries that start with the letter A</h3>
<input type="text" class="enumeration"><br>
<input type="text" class="enumeration"><br>
<input type="text" class="enumeration"><br>
<input type="text" class="enumeration"><br>
<input type="text" class="enumeration"><br>
<button>mark</button><label>score: <span>0</span></label>
```

Comment: I didn't know `includes` exists also i can understand how you do it. Thanks

Comment: follow up question.. what will happen if correct list array has 2 item. like for example. `{'id' : 8, 'ChoicesName': 'afghanistan'}`

Comment: @Strywyr; `includes` only works on an array - you would need to write a similar method that works with objects in an array - look at `entries()` for a start.

Comment: Again. thanks.. i'll check that